# How to integrate an ODE with second degree polynomial RHS

Tags: integration

I have : $dy/dt= k(a-y)(b-y)$ where $k$ is a constant

If I use variables separation, I have
d$y/(a-y)(b-y) = k \ dt$

I don't know how to proceed after. 
Can somebody help me?

Comment: Have you learned about partial fractions, Julia?

Comment: I don't remember, but I know that I need to use it. Can you give me an example?

Comment: @Julia, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html

Comment: @Julia: The idea behind partial fractions is to think to yourself, "What I have looks like the result of combining fractions by getting a common denominator. What could I have *started with* to end up with this?" This means you can plainly see the individual denominators, and you have to determine what would have been in the numerators that would make them combine to give this exact expression. That is **always** the motivation for this method.

Comment: Thank you, I understand how it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using partial fraction decomposition:

Starting the same way as lab bhattacharjee's solution, we have: $$\frac{1}{(a-y)(b-y)}dy=kdt$$

The goal is to split the left-hand side fraction into two simpler fractions. We can do this easily when we already have the factorization of the denominator (*i.e.*, $(a-y)(b-y)$). We must find constants $K_1, K_2$ that satisfy the following: $$\frac{1}{(a-y)(b-y)} = \frac{K_1}{a-y} + \frac{K_2}{b-y}$$

To find these constants, now multiply both sides by $(a-y)(b-y)$:
$$1 = K_1(b-y) + K_2(a-y)$$

This last equation must hold for *all* values of $y$, so you can start substituting any values you like. In this case, try substituting $y = a$ and $y = b$, and you will be able to find $K_1$ and $K_2$.

Finally, once you have these constants, you can integrate.

Answer (score 6):

HINT:

We have $$\frac{dy}{(a-y)(b-y)}=kdt$$

Now for $a\ne b$ use $\displaystyle \frac1{(a-y)(b-y)}=\frac1{a-b}\cdot\frac{(a-y)-(b-y)}{(a-y)(b-y)}=\frac1{a-b}\left(\frac1{b-y}-\frac1{a-y}\right)$

Comment: can you show me the next steps, I am not able to arrive at the good answer, y=a-(a-b)/(1+Ce^-kt(a-b))

Comment: @Julia, do you know $$\int\frac{dy}{a-y}?$$

Comment: it is =ln(a-y)+c

Comment: @Julia, Again, we know $$\ln A+\log B=\ln AB$$ when both term in the LHS are defined