# Solving $y' = k(a-y)(b-y)$ for $0<a<b$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

I am trying to solve for y in the nonlinear homogeneous ordinary differential equation
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = k(a-y)(b-y)$$.
So far I have used the method shown in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666296/how-to-integrate-a-multiplication) which is a separation of variables method, along with trying many U substitutions, integration factors and bernoulli's equation. I have tried solving the equation piece by piece by solving parts of it separately and adding the result, but I don't know how to treat the integration constants when combining the results.

I then went on to matlab to find the solution to the differential equation analytically by using the dsolve function with initial conditions of $y=0$ at $t=0$.

I have been able to verify my solution for the case when $a=b$ which is $y = a - \frac{a}{akt+1}$ using the boundary conditions. For that solution I simply used a variable change of $U = (a-y)^-1$ and then substituted y back at the end - this method is using bernoulli's equation.

Via the inspection of the matlab results for the general case where $0<a<b$ I have been able to see that the solution matlab gives seems to be $$y = a - \frac{b-a}{\exp(kt(b-a)+\ln(b/a))-1}$$ This is not certain as I had to use concrete numbers for the variables $a$, $b$ and $k$ and then figured out how they were featured in the answer(I made the variables prime so they would not be simplified in any of the manipulations and changed their values a couple of times to see the pattern).

However the answer I obtained, via the method which I linked to, i.e separation of variables by obtaining partial fractions, is $$y = a\frac{\exp(k(a-b)t)-1}{\exp(k(a-b)t+\ln(a/b))-1}$$ which I cannot show being the same as the answer I obtained via matlab.

In order to verify my answer I also tried taking the limit as $b$ tends to $a$, to see if I can get the same result as when $\frac{dy}{dt} = k(a-y)^2$ for the $a=b$ case, but I get a division by zero.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You separate and use fraction decomposition and ln function...

Comment: @Isham I have shown the answer I obtained via that method, which is the second one, but I am convinced that it is wrong as I cannot show it being the same in the limit b to a, as the solution for the case a=b.

Comment: I see but you don't need Bernouilli here

Comment: @Isham Thanks for the clarification. I believed that after I obtained my integration constant C, that I could take the limit b to a and get back the same answer as for the case a=b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = k(a-y)(b-y)$$
I suppose $a \ne b$
$$\frac{dy}{(y-a)(y-b)}= k{dt} $$
use fraction decomposition :
$$dy \left (\frac{1}{(a-b)(y-a)}+\frac {1}{(b-a)(y-b)} \right )= k{dt} $$
Integrate:
$$\int dy \left (\frac{1}{(y-a)}-\frac {1}{(y-b)} \right )= (a-b)(kt+C) $$
$$\ln{|y-a|}-\ln{|y-b|}= (a-b)(kt+C) $$
$$\left |\frac {y-a}{y-b} \right |= e^{(a-b)(kt+C)} $$
$$y(1 -e^{(a-b)(kt+C)})=a-b e^{(a-b)(kt+C)} $$
$$y(t)=\dfrac {a-b e^{(a-b)(kt+C)} }{1 -e^{(a-b)(kt+C)}}$$

**For $a =b$**
$$\frac{dy}{(y-a)^2}= k{dt}$$
Substitute $u=y-a$
$$\frac{du}{u^2}= k{dt}$$
$$\frac{1}{u}= -kt+C$$
$$y-a= \frac{1}{ -kt+C}$$
$$y(t)=a+ \frac{1}{C -kt}$$

Comment: So are you saying I cannot equate the two by taking the limit b to a? It turns out I had the same answer as the one you provided for the general form after the integration constant is figured out via the boundary conditions - assuming I calculated it correctly.

Comment: The final part of the question I am trying to solve asks me to "take the limit b to a and show that the two results are consistent with each other" - this is the part that made me assume I had done the general case wrong because I got a division by zero as I mention previously, when taking the limit. What would consistent mean in this context?

Comment: So how can I satisfy "by considering the limit b to a show that the two results are consistent with each other"?

Comment: The fraction decomposition you used and I used too is not valid for $a=b$ Thats why you need to treat the case $a=b$ apart. @Σbaryon

Comment: Yes I used the $U = (a-y)^-1$ substituaton, in order to get that one, I am just trying to answer the final part of showing that " the results are consistent" now

Comment: Maybe if you take the limit properly you may end with the correct answer I don't know I didnt' check the limit. @Σbaryon

Comment: @Σbaryon Maybe if you take the limit correctly it may lead to the same result. But you have an indetermination in the result you posted

Comment: What is the indetermination that you speak of?

Comment: @Σbaryon here you have for $a=b$ $ \implies y=a-\frac 0 0 $ $$y = a - \frac{b-a}{\exp(kt(b-a)+\ln(b/a))-1}$$

Comment: Yes, that is the result I tried to obtain from matlab, but I do not find it relevant as it does not agree with my own and the results from this post. But yes, that is the division by zero that I spoke of in my question, which also occurs in the answer that is verified from you and the other answer on this post. This is what I was confused about when answering "show that they are consistent with each other"

Comment: On a side note, where can I learn to implement mathjax into my work? Where did you learn or what resource are you using to convert your equations?

Comment: You have a tutorial here @Σbaryon  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference You mean here or elsewhere ?

Comment: I managed to show the results are conistent with each other, you can verify if this is correct below(see my answer). I used a tool to convert my equations, which is very handy

Comment: The mathjax tuto is really good if you have time to read it it will help you a lot. On the other hand when you see an answer you can always edit the answer..the code will appear. You can learn this way too. @Σbaryon

Answer (score 1):

In fact, this differential equation is well known under the term "logistic differential equation" and its solutions also. See [for example] (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogisticEquation.html), and the detailed explanation of the proof for example [here](https://slideplayer.com/slide/7588252/) where the logistic growth is seen as a modelization improvement over pure exponential growth (basic model : $y'=ay$ with solution $y=ce^{at}$).

This dates back from a 1845 article by P.F. Verhulst, about population growth published [here](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN129323640_0018?tify=%7B%22pages%22:[14],%22view%22:%22info%22%7D), very interesting if you are able to read french.

Comment: Oh his name sounds german but the article is in french. I understand now he's belgian Jean Marie. Thanks for the links

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider this equation as a Riccati equation
$$y'=k(y^2-(a+b)y+ab)$$ 
and use the parametrization $y=-\frac{u'}{ku}$ leading to the linear equation
$$
u''+(a+b)ku+abk^2u=0
$$
which has the obvious solution $u(t)=Ae^{-akt}+Be^{-bkt}$ so that
$$
y(t)=\frac{aAe^{-akt}+bBe^{-bkt}}{Ae^{-akt}+Be^{-bkt}}.
$$
This gives identical solutions if the ratio of $A$ and $B$ is the same, so that in the end this is a one-parameter family of solutions, as expected of a first order scalar ODE.

---

For the limit $b\to a$, one has to fix the initial value $y_0=\frac{aA+bB}{A+B}$, or $B(b-y_0)=A(y_0-a)$, so one can set $A=b-y_0$, $B=y_0-a$ and
$$
y(t)=\frac{a(b-y_0)e^{(b-a)kt}+b(y_0-a)}{(b-y_0)e^{(b-a)kt}+(y_0-a)}
$$
Now apply the l'Hopital rule to this limit of the form $\frac 00$, taking the $b$ derivatives at $b=a$ in numerator and denominator to get
$$
y_{b=a}(t)=\frac{a+a(a-y_0)kt+(y_0-a)}{1+(a-y_0)kt}=a+\frac{(y_0-a)}{1+(a-y_0)kt}
$$

Answer (score 0):

I was able to show that the general case is equivalent to the $$a=b$$ case in the limit $$b\rightarrow a$$ I done this by using L'Hospital's rule.

Using $$y = \frac{b(e^{kt(b-a)}-1)}{\frac{b}{a}e^{kt(b-a)}-1}$$ we get $$ \frac{\frac{\partial }{\partial b}(b(e^{kt(b-a)}-1))}{\frac{\partial }{\partial b}(\frac{b}{a}e^{kt(b-a)}-1)}$$ which becomes $$\frac{e^{kt(b-a)}-1 +kbte^{kt(b-a)}}{\frac{1}{a}e^{kt(b-a)}+\frac{kbt}{a}e^{kt(b-a)}}$$ So we end up with $$\lim_{b\to a} \frac{e^{kt(b-a)}-1 +kbte^{kt(b-a)}}{\frac{1}{a}e^{kt(b-a)}+\frac{kbt}{a}e^{kt(b-a)}} = \frac{e^{kt(a-a)}-1 +kate^{kt(a-a)}}{\frac{1}{a}e^{kt(a-a)}+\frac{kat}{a}e^{kt(a-a)}} = \frac{kat}{kt+\frac{1}{a}} = \frac{ka^{2}t}{kat+1}$$

This is equivalent to the first result where $$a=b$$

So the two results are shown to be consistent.

Comment: When you take the limit from the first case you should end with the formula for $a=b$. Take a look at Lutz's answer for the limit. @Σbaryon you are correct you need to use l'Hospital

Comment: @Isham $$\frac{ka^{2}t}{kat+1}$$ is just the same as $$a-\frac{a}{akt+1}$$

Comment: Yes I know it looks a bit dfifferent from the formula I got for the case $a=b$ is it the same for you ?

Comment: Your formula has not the Constant C...Only a and k. But the formula I derivated has a constant C.

Comment: I see why the formula you used for  the limit has no C constant in it @Σbaryon  where does it come from ?

Comment: @Isham Yes, that is because I applied the boundary conditions of $$y=0$$ at $$t=0$$

Comment: But you are supposed to show this for any t ... Why didn't you try to use l'hospital with the general formula ? With b $\to$ a. On the other hand you still have t ion your formula thats not zero then

Comment: @Isham the question I was solving first wanted the full solutions for both of the cases and then wanted to show that they are consistent

Comment: You are supposed to get the second formula from the first one when taking a limit

Comment: I made the calculation from my formula both formulas are the same when limit is taken $b \to a$  it's just that the constant has to be $C=0$